# Use NSNumberFormatter to map integer to letter?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to use NSNumberFormatter to map integers to letters or other strings that are not the number spelled out (i.e. 1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, etc)?

Comment: What mapping do you want?

Comment: I'm using iOS-Charts and want to replace yAxis values of 1 through 7 with emojis.  I believe that framework requires using NSNumberFormatter

Comment: There's a difference between mapping 1 -> a, 2 -> b, etc. and mapping the numbers to Emoji characters. You should update your question to be more specific.

Comment: I mentioned they are mapping to strings. Emojis are strong characters. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `NSNumberFormatter` for something like this. Possible approaches include:

- Get the `char` equivalent:

  ```
  - (char)characterForValue:(NSInteger)value {
      NSAssert(value >= 1 && value <= 26, @"expecting value 1-26, but received %ld", (long)value);

      return 'a' + value - 1;
  }
  ```
- Return a string of the character equivalent:

  ```
  - (NSString *)stringForValue:(NSInteger)value {
      NSAssert(value >= 1 && value <= 26, @"expecting value 1-26, but received %ld", (long)value);

      char c = 'a' + value - 1;
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
  }
  ```
- Have an array or dictionary or string that map your numeric values to strings or characters and look it up in that:

  ```
  - (NSString *)stringForValue:(NSInteger)value {
      NSString *characters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

      NSAssert(value >= 1 && value <= [characters length], @"expecting value 1-26, but received %ld", (long)value);

      return [characters substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(value - 1, 1)];
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  - (NSString *)stringForValue:(NSInteger)value {
      NSArray *strings = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"q", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"u", @"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z"];

      NSAssert(value >= 1 && value <= [strings count], @"expecting value 1-26, but received %ld", (long)value);

      return strings[value - 1];
  }
  ```

There are lots of other ways to tackle this, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea. But, bottom line, this is not a problem well suited for `NSNumberFormatter`.

---

If you wanted to use emoji, just have an array of those emojis and use that:

```
- (NSString *)stringForValue:(NSInteger)value {
    NSArray *strings = @[@"", @"", @"", @""];

    NSAssert(value >= 1 && value <= [strings count], @"expecting value 1-%ld, but received %ld", (long)[strings count], (long)value);

    return strings[value - 1];
}
```

Comment: For the `characterForValue:` method, I would change the `return` statement to something more readable: `return 'a' + value - 1;`. I believe the `'a'` is more self documenting than `96`.

Comment: Not a bad idea. But the real "take home" message is that this is not a job for `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: I'm using iOS charts - which is an awesome charting framework! - and unfortunately the only way to update the label values is through NSNumberFormatter.  Is there any way to do it with that class?

Comment: You might be able to do some kludgy `NSNumberFormatter` subclass, but that's definitely the wrong way to go. Most charting frameworks offer the ability to specify labels as strings (either by changing chart type or by specifying separate labels). If you're framework doesn't, then maybe it's not so awesome. ;) Or perhaps more likely, there's some way to do it which has eluded you thus far. Perhaps you should post a new question with the _real_ issue, namely that you want to figure out how to use text labels on your chart. And include a link to the particular charting library that you're using.